# How to adjust function left_join in shiny code

Tags: r, shiny

The code below works normally, I'm just having a brief problem as I also inserted `WeekS` in `wk_port2eng`. I did this because in my system, for example, `Monday` means `segunda-feira`, however in the system I study `Monday` means `segunda` in Portuguese. So I'm trying to merge to use both. But when I do `left_join`, `WeekS` is inserted into the generated table, but that's not what I want, I want it to work the same as `WeekP`. It goes something like this: `WeekP | WeekS` , that is, it is one or the other. So how can I adjust this in my code below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-18","2021-10-18","2021-10-28","2021-10-30")),
                       Week = c("Monday", "Monday", "Sunday", "Sunday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "FDE", "FDE", "FDE"),
                       time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange')
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')
                                 
                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min   = min(data()$date1))
  })
  
  observe({updateDateRangeInput(session,"daterange1",start = NA, end = NA)})
  
  wk_port2eng <- data.frame(
    WeekE = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
    WeekP = c("segunda-feira", "terca-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira",  "sexta-feira", "sabado", "domingo"),
    WeekS = c("segunda", "terca", "quarta", "quinta", "sexta", "sabado", "domingo")
  )
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    Test1 <- dplyr::filter(data(), date1 %in% days)
    weeks_inp <- unique(weekdays(days))  
    wk <- wk_port2eng[((wk_port2eng$WeekP %in% weeks_inp) | (wk_port2eng$WeekS %in% weeks_inp)),]
   #wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekE %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in English in your notebook
    
    weeks_ine <- wk$WeekE
    meanTest1 <- data() %>%
      group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week), Category) %>% 
      summarise(mean = mean(time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
    meanTest <- meanTest1[meanTest1$Week %in% as.character(weeks_ine),]
    
    left_join(meanTest, wk_port2eng, by = c("Week" = "WeekE")) %>%      
      arrange(match(WeekP, weekdays(input$daterange1))) %>%
      select(-WeekP)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**In Rstudio:**

```
[1] "domingo"       "segunda-feira" "terça-feira"   "quarta-feira"  "quinta-feira"  "sexta-feira"   "sábado"
```

**In shiny server:**

```
  [1] "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday" [7] "Saturday"
```

Comment: Replacing `select(-WeekP)` with `select(-WeekP,-WeekS)` should remove `WeekS` from your dataframe.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes, that's one of the things, but how would it be `arrange` since I only have `WeekP`? Is it possible to insert `WeekS` too in any way?Because it can be one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Now, it should work whether it is in English or Portuguese.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-18","2021-10-18","2021-10-28","2021-10-30")),
                       Week = c("Monday", "Monday", "Sunday", "Sunday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "FDE", "FDE", "FDE"),
                       time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

ui <- fluidPage(

  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange')
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')

                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  data <- reactive(Test)

  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min   = min(data()$date1))
  })

  observe({updateDateRangeInput(session,"daterange1",start = NA, end = NA)})

  wk_port2eng <- data.frame(
    WeekE = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
    WeekP = c("segunda-feira", "terca-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira",  "sexta-feira", "sabado", "domingo"),
    WeekS = c("segunda", "terca", "quarta", "quinta", "sexta", "sabado", "domingo")
  )

  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    Test1 <- dplyr::filter(data(), date1 %in% days)
    weeks_inp <- unique(weekdays(days))

    wk_p2e <- wk_port2eng %>%
                mutate(WeekPrS = if (sum(wk_port2eng$WeekS %in% weeks_inp) == length(weeks_inp)) WeekS else{
                  if (sum(wk_port2eng$WeekP %in% weeks_inp) == length(weeks_inp)) WeekP else WeekE
                }) %>%
                select(-WeekP, -WeekS)
    wk <- wk_p2e[wk_p2e$WeekPrS %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in Portuguese or English

    weeks_ine <- wk$WeekE
    meanTest1 <- data() %>%
      group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week), Category) %>%
      summarise(mean = mean(time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
    meanTest <- meanTest1[meanTest1$Week %in% as.character(weeks_ine),]

    left_join(meanTest, wk_p2e, by = c("Week" = "WeekE")) %>%
      arrange(match(WeekPrS, weekdays(input$daterange1)))  %>%
      select(-WeekPrS)
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I think that's right YBS, but I'm not managing to test it very well because it worked in Rstudio, but when I deploy it on Shiny server it doesn't. When I use `print(weekdays(days))`, it appears that my days are in English on the shiny server, but in Rstudio they are in Portuguese. You know how I can change shiny server local system to Portuguese too? I tried this: `Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", "pt_br.utf-8")`, but it didn't work. I inserted in the question of `print(weekdays(days))` to you see.

Comment: Try the updated code.  It should work either way.  No need to change the language in the server.